# Syncing an iPhone with a new laptop

Tags: windows-7, itunes, iphone

I have an iPhone 3GS, synced with a laptop that has now died.  I'm now sharing a laptop with my friend and she has her iPhone synced with it.

I want to sync my iPhone with her laptop without losing my data, then reload my stuff onto my new iPhone 4.

Please explain how I can have two seperate iTunes accounts for each phone, because we don't want each others' stuff.  Also, please explain how I can sync my old iPhone so i can sync my new iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new user account on your friends laptop.
2. Any content purchased from iTunes can be transferred from the iPhone to the computer
3. [Lifehacker Guide to copy data off iPod/iPhones](http://lifehacker.com/394046/copy-music-from-your-iphone-or-ipod-to-your-computer-for-free) - for the music you didn't buy from iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make it:

1. The simpler of the two ways is to set up iTunes with separate playlists. Create a playlist for each iPhone or each person who will be synching an iPhone with your one installation of iTunes.
2. For each iPhone, set up iTunes to sync only the playlists you want on that iPhone. When you plug an iPhone into the computer, the computer recognizes which iPhone it is, and you're on your way to synchronization.
3. What if the easy way won't work for you? Perhaps you have accounts set up on your computer especially for your children that restrict what they can do on the computer. If you want your children to be able to sync their own iPhones while signed in to their own user accounts on the computer, that's possible as well. Each user can have an individual Library in iTunes with this method.
4. If the child's user account does not currently give them access to the iTunes application, sign in to your computer as admin. Edit the child's user account. Grant access to the iTunes program in the Programs or Applications folder of your computer--then sign in to your child's account and open iTunes. You will still want to set up which playlists from iTunes will be synched to the chlld's iPhone in the way described previously.